# Extraction with awk based on position-specific hit in a string

Tags: awk, substr

I have a large txt file that looks like this (tab separated):

```
147 186741 2S74M -162
147 647172 1S75M -221
163 584665 74M2S 271
147 658416 5S65M6S -272
```

I want the `awk` to look at the 3rd column and extract the whole line when it encounters the character "S" in either in the 2nd or 3rd position. Alternatively, discard all lines where character "S" is on the last position of that string.

Thank you in advance,
TP

Comment: What about the last line? Should this line be discarded since there is an S in last position, or should be kept since there is an S in second position?

Comment: I just didn't really know where to start in terms of code, that's why I went for a straight "give me the answer" question. I'll try to avoid that in the future. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '$3 ~ /S$/ {next} $3 ~ /^..?S/' file
```

The first part skips lines where S is the last character of the third field.
The next part prints the line when S is the 2nd or 3rd character.

Comment: Yup, this will do it! Actually, the only peace I was missing was "/^..?S/"  but it's good to have the first part two as now I can parse for entries that have only S at the beginning without having the S at the end, or keep all the entries that have S at the beginning regardless if they have it at the end. Beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$3~/^.(S|.S).*[^S]$/' file
```

The output:

```
147 186741 2S74M -162
147 647172 1S75M -221
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
awk '$3 !~ /S$/' file
```